# xlop alignment of multiple equations when resultstyle=text

Tags: align, amsmath, alignat, xlop

Is there a way to align xlop equations when the resultstyle is text

```
    \documentclass[20pt,fleqn,leqno]{extarticle}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop

    \begin{document}

        \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
            \item { \opadd[style=text] {61}{7} }
            \item {\opadd[style=text] {1}{7} }
            \item {\opadd[style=text] {161}{7} }
            \item {\opadd[style=text] {1}{700} }
        \end{enumerate}

    \end{document}
```

Current output

[image]

Desired output
(opereator and equal to sign aligned, if place value alignment can be done that will be great too).

[image]

I am constrained to use xlop for some reason but if this is not possible with xlop, I will look at other regular math equation options.

edit:  Does it make it easier if the output follows regular alignment rules like this?
[image]

ps: Trying to keep the solution to xlop as output is getting generated conditionally in a larger program - not using the opadd with style text will require access to code I do not have. The proposed solutions are much appreciated.

Comment: You can do very well without xlop, why do you need xlop?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see it possible to change the output of `xlop` to meet the esoteric needs of the question, namely to make the first number right aligned and the second number left aligned, using a field width that, at the invocation of problem 1, cannot be fully known.

However, if the problem were reduced to using the standard `xlop` output, but aligning at the equal sign, then it could be done.

For the sample problem, involving only addition and positive numbers, one could do this.  Basically, I use `\numexpr` to calculate the result, and add the appropriate number of blanks spaces to the end of the right-aligned result.  The field width for the `\mopadd` macro is specified in the definition `\mopwid`.

```
\documentclass[20pt,fleqn,leqno]{extarticle}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xlop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xlop
\def\mopwid{1.8in}
\newcommand\mopadd[2]{\makebox[\mopwid][r]{%
  \opadd[style=text] {#1}{#2}%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1+#2\relax<1000\relax\phantom{0}\fi%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1+#2\relax<100\relax\phantom{0}\fi%
  \ifnum\numexpr#1+#2\relax<10\relax\phantom{0}\fi%
}}
\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[label={\arabic*)}]
        \item { \mopadd{61}{7} }
        \item {\mopadd{1}{7} }
        \item {\mopadd{161}{7} }
        \item {\mopadd{1}{700} }
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As indicated by AndreC, the problem is really made for something in the `align` family, rather than `xlop`, given that all 4 problems have to be provided in advance for the proper field widths to be known.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you want this, because the alignment will be rather weird.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,xlop}

\newenvironment{additions}
 {%
  \par
  \vspace{\topsep}%
  \setcounter{enumi}{0}%
  \renewcommand{\theenumi}{(\arabic{enumi})}%
  \renewcommand{\item}{%
    \refstepcounter{enumi}%
    \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\theenumi}%
  }%
  \renewcommand{\opadd}[3][]{&##2&##3&\the\numexpr##2+##3\relax}%
  \noindent
  \tabular{
    @{}
    c
    >{$}r<{$}
    @{${}+{}$}
    >{$}l<{$}
    @{${}={}$}
    l
    @{}
  }
 }{%
   \endtabular
   \par\vspace{\topsep}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{additions}
\item \opadd[style=text]{61}{7} \\
\item \opadd[style=text]{1}{7} \\
\item \opadd[style=text]{161}{7} \\
\item \opadd[style=text]{1}{700} \\
\end{additions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a simple `array`:

```
\documentclass[20pt,fleqn,leqno]{extarticle}
\newcounter{No}  
\newcommand\opadd[2]{\stepcounter{No}(\theNo) & #1 & #2 & \the\numexpr#1+#2\relax}
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{r @{\quad} r @{\,+\,} l @{\,=\,} l }
\opadd{61}{7} \\
\opadd{1}{7}\\
\opadd{161}{7}\\ 
\opadd{1}{700} \\
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

The next array needs a preceeding `\setcounter{No}{0}`

[image]